# Chamada em função jQuery não encontra arquivo

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp

Fiz uma função jQuery e na passagem do URL ele não está achando o arquivo. Achei estranho ele não encontrar, pois o arquivo existe.

Toda chamada que eu tenho dentro do site, é sempre a mesma, seja `src` ou `href`, a chamada é a mesma, assim:

`../../pasta_base/pasta_secundária/nome_do_arquivo.asp`

Para dar um exemplo no meu caso, eu faço assim:

`../../prs/asp/prs0061b_crossbrowser.asp`.

Essa forma funciona e eu consigo encontrar o arquivo. É dessa forma que está em todo o site. Porém, quando eu chamo pelo jQuery, me retorna o erro 404, *page not found*.

Não sei se tem a ver por estar em uma função jQuery. Como estamos reescrevendo o site, para funcionar no Chrome, não há função jQuery da forma como eu fiz, essa é a primeira. Veja como está a minha função:

```
function CarregaTabela() {
    var str = "";
    $.ajax({
        url: '../../prs/asp/prs0061b_crossbrowser.asp',//aqui não acha nada
        datatype: 'json',
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        type: 'POST',
        data: JSON.stringify({}),
        success: function (data) {    
            //$(data.resultado_acao).each(function () {                        
            })    
        },
        error: function (error) {
        }
    })    
}
```

Só gostaria de saber, se o que eu fiz está correto, se é dessa forma. Faço assim com MVC, mas lá no URL eu coloco `action/controller`, agora com arquivo direto não sei se está correto. É ASP clássico.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Descobri uma forma de pegar a URL base, sem ter que colocar fixo, na mão. O ASP faz assim:

```
<%=Request.ServerVariables("HTTP_HOST")%>
```

Então minha função jquery/ajax ficou assim:

```
function CarregaTabela() {
           var sUrl = $('#sUrl').val();
            var str = "";

        $.ajax({
            url: sUrl,
            datatype: 'json',
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            type: 'POST',
            data: JSON.stringify({cod_prestador_ts:}),
            success: function (data) {

                $('#cbxAcao').html(data);

            },
            error: function (error) {
            }
        })
    }
```

Aqui meu hidden:

```
<input type="hidden" name="sUrl" id="sUrl" value='http://<%=Request.ServerVariables("HTTP_HOST")%>/prs/asp/prs0061b_crossbrowser.asp' />
```

Comment: Por favor, marque a resposta como certa para não ficar retornando à página inicial.

Comment: @dvd, Faz muito tempo essa pergunta e não estou mais na empresa há mais de 10 meses. Saí em Fev desse ano. Mas cho que minha resposta resolveu, porem disse a algumas pessoas aqui que não gostaria de marcar a minha resposta, para não pensarem que eu estou burlando, ou seja, pergunto e depois respondo para ganhar reputação. A outra resposta não tenho como testar. O que a comunidade decidir eu faço.

Comment: Nao tem problema em marcar a propria resposta. Isso nao eh burlar nao. Eh pq eh uma pergunta antiga e fica voltando pra pagina inicial. Marcar a propria resposta, se ela for a que resolveu o problema, eh ateh recomendado pelo site. Abs!

Answer (score 0):

Coloca em seu `<body>` a seguinte propriedade:

`<body data-base-url="http://www.seusite.com.br/">`

Aonde está seu site, você tem que digitar o comando absoluto até chegar na pasta anterior a `prs` ou deixar assim. Daí na URL do JS você continua ela até chegar na pasta `prs`.

**Não pode ter** `../../` na URL do seu `JS`.

Daí crie uma variável global no topo do script.

`var baseURL = $('body').data('base-url');`

E na função coloque a variável **`baseURL`** antes da URL:

```
    function CarregaTabela() {
        var str = "";
        $.ajax({
            url: baseURL + '/prs/asp/prs0061b_crossbrowser.asp',// agora vai achar
            datatype: 'json',
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            type: 'POST',
            data: JSON.stringify({}),
            success: function (data) {    
                //$(data.resultado_acao).each(function () {                        
                })
            },
            error: function (error) {
            }
        })    
    }
```

Comment: Então, mas veja minha situação. Hoje eu tenho um ambiente de teste que é diferente do ambiente de publicação. Além do meu ambiente, há o de homol. Se eu digitar manualmente o meu path, isso vai dar zebra, se for publicado em outro ambiente. A forma ../../, ela pega o ambiente base e depois apenas completo com as devidas pastas e nome do arquivo.

Comment: Você não está digitando manualmente. Quando você coloca uma URL como base de tudo você define a base do site. Vamos supor, **http://www.dominio.com.br/admin**. Daí no JS você tem que entrar na pasta **produtos** dentro de **imagens**. Então faz assim: `baseURL + '/imagens/produtos'`. Se não tivesse a base você teria que usar o `../../` pra voltar na base, porquê você está dentro da pasta `js` talvez por causa do arquivo atual. Mas se no seu ambiente de produção tiver uma pasta `public` já quebra duas pernas. Mas usando a URL base não. Visto que o `htaccess` controla o acesso a `public`.